# Extracting texts from html tags

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have a page like this which has 3 values in `li` tags

```
<li>nafiz</li>
<li>ACE</li>
<li>Sanah</li>
```

And this code gives me only the last innertext:

```
public string names = "";
    public string names2 = "";
    public string names3 = "";


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(openUrl);

    foreach (HtmlNode nd in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li"))
        {
            names=nd.InnerText.ToString();

        }
```

How can I store all 3 values in those strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will be easier if you store the 3 values in string array or list, for example :

```
var names = new List<string>();
.....
.....
foreach (HtmlNode nd in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li"))
{
    names.Add(nd.InnerText.Trim());
}
```

`InnerText` is already of type `string` no need to put additional `ToString()`. `Trim()` in above example meant to clear the `name` from leading and trailing white-spaces.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function

```
    string[] GetItems(string htmlText)
    {
        List<string> Answer = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < htmlText.Length; i++)
        {
            int start = htmlText.IndexOf('>', i);
            i = start;
            int end = htmlText.IndexOf('<', i);

            if (end == -1 || start == -1)
                break;

            string Item = htmlText.Substring(start + 1, end - start - 1);
            if (Item.Trim() != "")
                Answer.Add(Item);

            i = end + 1;
        }
        return Answer.ToArray();
    }
```

and use it...

```
     foreach (string item in GetItems(YourText))
     {
          MessageBox.Show(item);
     }
```